# why is flatbuffers and nng no copy is slower that double copy

Tags: c++11, flatbuffers, nanomsg

i am using flatbuffers and nng. using FB i am creating seralized buffers and adding it to nng msg. I wanted to eliminate this copying of FB to NNG.

To achieve this i wrote a custom allocator as below.

```
class CustomAllocator : public flatbuffers::Allocator
{
private:
    nng_msg *m_nng_msg = nullptr;

public:

    ~CustomAllocator()
    {
        if (m_nng_msg) {
            nng_msg_free(m_nng_msg);
            m_nng_msg = nullptr;
        }
    }

    nng_msg *get() { return m_nng_msg; }

    nng_msg *release()
    {
        nng_msg *t_nng_msg = m_nng_msg;
        m_nng_msg = nullptr;
        return t_nng_msg;
    }

    uint8_t *allocate(size_t size) override
    {
        if (nng_msg_alloc(&m_nng_msg, size) != 0) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        return static_cast<uint8_t *>(nng_msg_body(m_nng_msg));
    }

    void deallocate(uint8_t *p, size_t size) override
    {
        if (m_nng_msg) {
            nng_msg_free(m_nng_msg);
            m_nng_msg = nullptr;
        }
    }
};
```

and then attaching it to FB as below

```
CustomAllocator allocator;
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder(1024, &allocator);
... fill using builder

nng_msg *msg = allocator.get();
nng_msg_trim(msg, nng_msg_len(msg) - builder.GetSize()); // this is required as FB adds data to the end of the buffer, i checked the *_trim and it does not do realloc
nng_msg_set_pipe(msg, pipe);
nng_sendmsg(s, msg, 0);
```

for the case of double copy i use it like this

```
flatbuffers::FlatBufferBuilder builder(1024);
... fill using builder
nng_msg *msg = nullptr;
nng_msg_alloc(&msg, 0);
nng_msg_append(msg, builder.GetBufferPointer(), builder.GetSize());
nng_msg_set_pipe(msg, pipe);
nng_sendmsg(s, msg, 0);
```

My expectation was that no-copy would be be slightly better than double copy. But when i ran tests i am getting different results.

So i am wondering what could be the cause of this behavior?

each scenario was run 20 times to get the avg times.

```
Message Size      180 bytes
Message Count     20000             80000             100000
                  no-copy  copy     no-copy  copy     no-copy  copy
time in ms        198      185      809      784      997      950
std-dev            47       44       85       66       72       83
```

Comment: Given the huge std-dev in your times it is almost as if both techniques are equally fast, and the overhead is elsewhere. Rather than averaging, why not take the min, and run your tests a bit longer?

Comment: i tried running the tests for 10 mins with 2048 bytes message size and everytime double copy won by 10-20 ms except for 100k loop. so i don't see any advantage of using custom allocator.

Comment: Are your certain `allocate()`/`deallocate()` only gets called once per message?

Comment: Yes. I verified that.